# Does Authorize.net/CiviCRM integration require the use of "Webhooks" instead of "Silent Post"?

Tags: wordpress, payment-processor, authorize.net, integration

I'm nervous that Civi's documentation for Authorize.net is outdated. There appear to be cases where recurring ARB payments are processed by Authorize but the related Civi contributions & memberships are not updated. [This doc](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/payment-processors/authorize-net/#automated-recurring-billing) seems to require the use of a "Silent Post", but tech support at Authorize said Silent Post is deprecated. [Other systems](https://docs.hyros.com/authorize-net-integration/) that integrate with Authorize use webhooks instead of the Silent Post. Should I be using webhooks instead of the Silent Post? If so, should I use the same format, like this for Wordpress:

```
https://example.com/BASEPAGE/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/payment/ipn/NN
```

If so continued... which events should be listened to?

- All Events
- Customer Events
- Subscription Events
- Payment Events

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the [authnet extension](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/authnet) instead which uses webhooks and not a silent post URL.

Here is the [setup](https://docs.civicrm.org/authnetecheck/en/latest/setup/) guide and if you are [migrating from legacy core authnet](https://docs.civicrm.org/authnetecheck/en/latest/migration/). The webhooks are created automatically if you check the system status page in Civi to generate them. FYI, the webhooks used are:
[image]

Comment: This is a correct answer, and one I would endorse - but to be clear, the "Silent Post URL" has been deprecated for many years and I don't think it will be disabled in the next several years.  So it's good to use the authnet extension, but Silent Post URL is still a workable solution.

Comment: Agreed. I am wondering if it would work out okay to have the core authnet processor (using silent post URL and needed for existing ARB's) and the https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/authnet (using webhook) in use at the same time? I *think* so.